# Error while using DocumenttermMatrix function in R

Tags: r, tm

I have taken generic text of 1000 rows and performed the below in the process of textmining. While using the document Term matrix I am not getting the count of words as output in the matrix.

```
>def<-read.csv("Defect.csv",header = T)
>docs<-Corpus(VectorSource(def$Summary))
>docs<-tm_map(docs,content_transformer(tolower))
>docs<-tm_map(docs,removeNumbers)
>docs<-tm_map(docs,removeWords,stopwords("english"))
>docs<-tm_map(docs,removePunctuation)
>docs<-tm_map(docs,stripWhitespace)
>docs<-tm_map(docs,stemDocument,language = "english")

>docs[[1]]$content
[1] "access logout access employe separ modul"

>dtm<-DocumentTermMatrix(docs)
>data.matrix(dtm)
```

Below is the output I got for DTM

> Terms
>   Docs   access logout modul separ approv button click display error

I am not getting the word count in a matrix. Not sure of what could be the error here.

Comment: use `m <- as.matrix(dtm); sort(rowSums(m), decreasing = TRUE)` to get your desired output

Comment: i am getting 
837 789 554 727   6  93 
 40  38  29  29  28  28
but not the word count respectively

Comment: names(m) is giving me a NULL output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def<-read.csv("Defect.csv",header = T)
docs<-Corpus(VectorSource(def$Summary))
docs<-tm_map(docs,content_transformer(tolower))
docs<-tm_map(docs,removeNumbers)
docs<-tm_map(docs,removeWords,stopwords("english"))
docs<-tm_map(docs,removePunctuation)
docs<-tm_map(docs,stripWhitespace)
docs<-tm_map(docs,stemDocument,language = "english")
```

Note : use `TermDocumentMatrix` over `DocumentTermMatrix`

```
dtm <- TermDocumentMatrix(docs)
m <- as.matrix(dtm)
v <- sort(rowSums(m),decreasing=TRUE)
d <- data.frame(word = names(v),freq=v)
rownames(d) <- NULL
```

Now, your dataframe should look like..

```
> head(d,10)
        word freq
1       file  157
2       data  151
3  incorrect  136
4     target  120
5       issu   95
6       tabl   82
7      sourc   69
8     column   63
9        get   61
10   process   56
```

Comment: thankyou Parth, this worked. Whats the difference between DocumentTermMatrix and TermDocumentMatrix

Comment: @praneeth in case of `TermDocumentMatrix`, it reduces the number of columns (documents) but keeps the number of rows (words). For eg.  create `dtm1 <- TermDocumentMatrix(docs)` and `dtm2 <- DocumentTermMatrix(docs)` and compare the structures using `str(dtm1); str(dtm2)`

Comment: you'll notice the peculiar difference in `$ dimnames` attribute, the `Docs` and `Terms` are reversed in both

Comment: Got the difference.. Its more like a transpose

Comment: @praneeth, exactly ...just as the function names suggest :), their application depends on user requirement

Comment: well thanks parth, but what i am looking for is the matrix of words count in a sentence. like
    #             ab abstract accelerate accept
                  1    0            0               1                     #
from which i wish to build a model, but this DTM or TDM is not helping me .. im not able to see that matrix

Comment: @praneeth, isn't matrix `m` solving a similar issue here ?...giving word occurence matrix

Comment: No parth it isn't.. Anyway i used the same code in r console it worked.. But didn't work in rstudio

Comment: @mpc, got context you're working on... will share an update if i find something, and regarding "_didn't work in rstudio_", make sure  absolute `path` to files is all ok